# How to sum m1 and m2 in this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query for result show
Now, I need sum m1, m2

Query is:

```
select metraj, fee, tedad, fee_tedad,
       metraj * fee AS m1,
       tedad * fee_tedad AS m2 
from content 
where id = 54
```

Comment: Try to add `metraj * fee + tedad * fee_tedad`. You cannot consume the alias of the `SELECT` clause inside the `SELECT`.

Comment: Any reason why you tagged jquery?

Comment: When you say sum do you mean per row or total across all rows?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
select metraj, fee, tedad, fee_tedad,
       metraj * fee AS m1,
       tedad * fee_tedad AS m2,
       metraj * fee+tedad * fee_tedad as sum
from content 
where id = 54
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select metraj, fee, tedad, fee_tedad, metraj * fee AS m1, tedad * fee_tedad AS m2, mtraj * fee + tedad * fee_tedad as m1_plus_m2 from content where id = 54
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work :

```
select metraj, fee, tedad, fee_tedad, (metraj * fee) + (tedad * fee_tedad) AS someVariable, from content where id = 54
```

If you need both m1 and m2 also then use the following :

```
select metraj, fee, tedad, fee_tedad, metraj * fee AS m1, tedad *fee_tedad AS m2, (metraj * fee) + (tedad * fee_tedad) AS someVariable  from content  where id = 54
```